# Removing closed questions from Highest Votes list?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, purim-torah-policy, closed-questions

There's a wonderful [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14756/rejecting-others-friend-requests-on-facebook) that currently ranks #5 on the [questions sorted by votes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) list.

This seems like bad form to me.  I'd rather have that list full of real questions that people actually care about.  Can closed questions be removed from that list?

Comment: Is this about all closed questions or all closed PTIJ questions?

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess this is for any closed question.  However, most non-PTIJ closed questions get removed fairly soon after they are closed, and therefore there is no issue like this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This can be accomplished in one of two ways:

1. **Delete the question**. This is probably obvious.
2. **Put a historical lock on the question**. This is a special status that moderators can place on a given question, which will preserve it and all of its answers on the site but prevent any future modifications. **It will also remove it from all default lists** - you'll still be able to find it by searching for it, but it won't show up to casual readers.

Option #1 is preferred for questions that have simply outlived their usefulness. Option #2 was created explicitly for questions that are/were enjoyable and worth keeping around as a reminder of the site's history, but which shouldn't normally be held up as examples of good questions.

Comment: "Option 1: Delete the question".....but we like our Purim Torah....

Comment: Well, that's why option #2 exists!

Comment: Can locked questions be unlocked?  (Occasionally Purim Torah gets un-closed for another go)

Comment: Yes they can, @yez

Comment: We tried this before, and chose against locking because it's hard to search for them and the tag self-destructs (IIRC). There should be a record of the discussion then somewhere...

Comment: See deleted comments [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/797/759) and chat transcripts from that day [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3782396#3782396) [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3783751#3783751) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3785415#3785415)

Comment: Oh and how convenient! http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3784101#3784101